# Updating a form in PHP through mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I am building a list where the user can update or delete the existing contacts. I have created index.php, which successfully sends out the contacts to database. The list.php displays the list of contacts entered from index.php in a table. Now, the user should either Delete or Edit each contact.

Unfortunately, my edit_user.php returns an error after I hit Edit: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.**
Also, when I hit Edit in my list.php, I want the edit_user.php show the edit form with pre-filled contact info.

I am a newbie to web development. Sorry, there is so much code. Please help me spot my error. 
Here is config.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'mysql51-031.wc2.dfw1.stabletransit.com';
$dbuser = '549359_sargis';
$dbpass = '********';
$dbname = '549359_sargis';
$table  = 'Contacts';

$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection) or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

Here is my list.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact List</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
                <a href="index.php">Create New Contact</a><hr/>

</head>
<body>
    <?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Contacts", $connection);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows > 0)
    {

        echo "<center><h1>Contact List: (Updated)</h1><table border = '1'>";
            echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th> Firstname </th>";
                    echo "<th> Lastname </th>";
                    echo "<th> Email </th>";
                    echo "<th> Phone </th>";
                    echo "<th> Date </th>";
                    echo "<th> Action </th>";
                echo "</th>";
            echo "</thead>";

            echo "<tbody>";

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Contacts");
            while($record = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $record['firstname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $record['lastname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $record['phone_number'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $record['timesstamp'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>"; ?>
                <a href="edit_user.php"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />Edit</a>
                <?php echo "| <a href='list.php?action=delete&id=$id'>Delete</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";
            echo "</center>";
    }
    else
        echo "<center><h4>No contacts found.</h4></center>";

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is edit_user.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit User</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
//if (isset($_POST))
{
        $id = intval($_POST['id']);
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];

            $sql = "UPDATE Contacts SET firstname='".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."', lastname='".mysql_real_escape_string($lastname)."', email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', phone_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($phonenumber)."', timesstamp =NOW() WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($id);
            //$sql = "UPDATE Contacts SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', email='$email', phone_number='$phonenumber', timesstamp =NOW() WHERE id=$id";
            //print_r($_POST).'<br />';echo $sql;exit;
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if($result) 
            {
                header("Location: list.php");
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "There was a problem with the query: ".mysql_error().".";
            }
}


?>
<body>
            <form action="edit_user.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="POST">
                <div>
                    First name: <input type ='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"/><br />
                    Last name: <input type = 'text' id='lastname' name='lastname'value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"/><br />
                    Email: <input type = 'text' id='email' name='email' value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br />
                    Phone Number: <input type = 'text' id='phone_number' name='phonenumber' value="<?php echo $phonenumber; ?>"/><br />
                    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value='Update' />
                </div>
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look into Mysqli/PDO, for your own sake. As MYSQL is now deprecated and will be removed in future releases of PHP.
Here's a pretty comprehensive primer [How To use PHP Improved Mysqli - And Why You Should](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this error is a result of invalid characters not being escaped in the SQL statement.

But there are some things I would recommend changing.

First move the

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
```

to AFTER

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Also, just for kicks, change:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

to:

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
```

Then in your SQL statement, change it to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Contacts SET firstname='".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."', lastname='".mysql_real_escape_string($lastname)."', email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', phone_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($phonenumber)."', timesstamp =NOW() WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

Comment: I have done so. The error does not appear anymore, but my contact does not get updated either.

Comment: do this - just after the $sql ="UPDATE ..." line add: print_r($_POST).'<br />';echo $sql;exit;  See what the post vars look like and make sure they appear correct and then look at the sql statement that is displayed and make sure it's valid.  Something is incorrect here and it's either an escape issue or the id is not getting set correctly.

Comment: That was a really helpful function.
I see that the issue is that my id=0, instead of the id I want it to be. 

Array ( [firstname] => UPDATED_NAME [lastname] => UPDATED_LASTNAME [email] => UPDATED_EMAIL [phonenumber] => 1111111 [submit] => Update ) UPDATE Contacts SET firstname='UPDATED_NAME', lastname='UPDATED_LASTNAME', email='UPDATED_EMAIL', phone_number='1111111', timesstamp =NOW() WHERE id=0

Comment: This should fix it:  change edit_user.php?id=<?php echo $id;?> to just edit_user.php and then add a hidden field <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

Comment: and also change the $_GET for the id to $_POST

Comment: I tried using hidden field that but the id still shows as id=0. Thus, my contact does not get updated. I am thinking the problem could be the way I am passing variables from list.php to edit_user.php. I cannot see the problem though.
I also changed back to POST method.

Comment: I went to my database on phpMyAdmin and manually changed the id of a contact to 0 and my contact got updated.
Basically, my problem is that all my $_POST variables dont contain anything. They are not passed from list.php to edit_user.php. 
Might you know why is that happening?

Comment: in your edit form, try changing the hidden field value to <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> since the id is being passed presumably in the URL.  Make sure that the value that is being passed in the url to the edit page is passing the right id (not 0).  View the source of the page and look at the form after making the change as noted herein and it should be correct and matches the value as passed in the url.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a link edit :

```
<a href="edit_user.php?id=<? echo $record['id']; ?>" > Edit </a>
```

In this case id is a get Parameter not a POST parameter....

So in edit_user.php, it should be:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: I made the following change, however, my contact still does not update

Comment: Is your script redirecting to header("Location: list.php");   ?

Comment: Try to replace  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) BY    if (isset($_POST))

Comment: Tried both. My id still passes as 0.

Comment: I got it ! it doesnt know the id, you should had an hidden field in the form which contains the id of the user like below:  <input type ='hidden' id='id' name='id' value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

Comment: Since I manually changed my contact id to 0 in my database, the id still passes as 0. In other words, even when I try to update 10th contact from my list, the program will update (overwrite) the first contact, whose id = 0. ID still does not pass its value from list.php to edit_user.php. Neither the rest of my $_POST variables get passed.